# Why lambda function cannot be created in AWS NodeJS SDK after assuming Role with external ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-roles

AWS.Lambda.createFunction returns error message: "Failed to create Lambda function: InvalidParameterValueException: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda."

I am trying to create a lambda function to a third party AWS account via IAM Role delegation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_third-party.html?icmpid=docs_iam_console

In the third party account, the IAM Role was created with an external ID.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html

Role ARN: 'arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/Third-party'

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/admin"
                ],
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:ExternalId": "abcde"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Following parameter is used to assume the role. It returns the credentials.

```
const assumeRoleRequestParam: AWS.STS.AssumeRoleRequest = {
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/Third-party',
    ExternalId: 'abcde',
    RoleSessionName: 'DeployLambaFunction'
}
```

Lambda function is created as follows.

```
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyID,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: sessionToken
});

const functionParams: AWS.Lambda.CreateFunctionRequest = {
    FunctionName: 'deploy-test',
    Runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
    Handler: 'index.handler',
    Role: 'arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/Third-party',
    Code: {
        ZipFile: fs.readFileSync("helloworld.js.zip")
    },
};

lambda.createFunction(functionParams, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Failed to create Lambda function:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Lambda function created successfully:', data);
    }
});
```

It returns the error message given above. But it works if I don't use the external ID in the Role.

I expect creating lambda function should work fine when I use external ID in the IAM role, as it works when I do not use external ID. I checked the AWS documentations and the internet for similar issues, but I find none. Am I missing something?

Comment: *"I expect creating lambda function should work fine when I use external ID in the IAM role, as it works when I do not use external ID."* - why would you expect that? The lambda service cannot assume that role because it cannot pass the right external id. Split the assume-role-policy into two statements, one for your manual assume-role with the external id condition and one for the assume-role from the lambda service without such a condition.

Comment: @luk2302 the valid credentials are passed to AWS.Lambda object after assuming the role by calling AWS.STS.assumeRole(). When I call AWS.Lambda.createFunction my assumption is it already is using the credentials, there should be no need to pass external ID as evident by the lack of such parameter in the signature. Do you mean AWS.Lambda.createFunction cannot work in this case or how do I pass the external ID here?

Comment: What error message do you get? I am saying that the lambda service will not allow you to create that function because the lambda service *will* be unable to assume that role. The fact that *you* assumed that role right now is irrelevant to the service. At least that is what I am guessing is happening for lack of any actual error message.

Comment: okay understood. The error I'm getting from AWS.Lambda.createFunction "Failed to create Lambda function: InvalidParameterValueException: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda."
So in this case how can I make sure the lambda service uses the same external ID? Or is this not possible at all? Any link/resource will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Not possible. And no link/resource because there is no resource listing all the stuff that is not possible. Lack of documentation *for* such a feature is enough. And there is no such feature / parameter listed on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateFunction.html

Comment: Your suggestion works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @luk2302, the issue is because lambda service itself cannot assume the role with the external ID.

Solution is to split the role policy into two statements, one for the manual assume-role with the external ID condition and one for the assume-role from the lambda service without such a condition.

Example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/admin"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:ExternalId": "abcde"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```